# How should a user send mail from my website to me in asp.net 2.0

Tags: html, asp.net-2.0

In my website I want to give a link through which user can send mail to me.

Answer (score 4):

Simple MailTo

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu">mail me</a>
```

MailTo with Multiple Recipients

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu,ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">mail me</a>
```

MailTo with Subject

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?subject=Comments from MailTo Syntax Page">mail me</a>
```

MailTo with a Copy

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?cc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">mail me</a>
```

MailTo with a Blind Copy

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?bcc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU">mail me</a>
```

MailTo with message already started in Body

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?body=I am having trouble finding information on ">mail me</a>
```

MailTo with multiline message in Body

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?body=The message's first paragraph.%0A%0aSecond paragraph.%0A%0AThird Paragraph.">mail me</a>
NOTE: Use "%0A" for a new line, use "%0A%0A" for a new line preceded by a blank line.
```

Features may be used in combination

MailTo with Subject, a Recipient, a Copy and a Blind Copy

```
<a href="mailto:astark1@unl.edu?subject=MailTo Comments&cc=ASTARK1@UNL.EDU&bcc=id@internet.node">mail me</a>
```

> It is recommended that you use a
>   process other than MailTo handle the
>   e-mail process from your web site.
>
> If you do use MailTo, please encode
>   the included e-mail address(s) to
>   reduce the spam for that address.

[Source](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html)

Comment: problem with using mailto: is that you get spammed silly by bots that traul for mail links. I'd rather seen an enquiry form written and sent with .Net.Mail.SmtpClient like DevStuff has suggested. A Captcha is a must too

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="mailto:dnyaneshwar@example.com">Mail me</a>
```

When the user clicks the link that this will make on your website, their default email program will open, with your e-mail address in the "to" field.

This has nothing to do with ASP.net 2.0 - it will work on any web page in any web browser, no matter how that web page is generated.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to expose an email address to spammers I'd recommend creating a contact form (with a CAPTCHA) and use the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` and `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` classes.